# How to show image when we post a comment?

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

When I post a comment for a post or page in WordPress by default it shows a Gravatar image. I don't want this. Is there any way to upload an image when a user posts a comment in WordPress? I need to give people a way to upload their own image when posting a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

those images are not uploaded or set by wordpress, its another service called [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)
you sign up with that service then on any blog that is using the gravatar feature, the image is linked to from there site.

Comment: Can I use my own image through gravatar ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload it by using Gravtar, for that u need a wordpress login username and password.
And it is free to register.
Enjoy Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is the same answer as @Marty's, but with poorer grammar. Who upvoted this?

Comment: Countering what appears to be two meaningless downvotes. To be fair I upvoted the accepted answer too, but only because both are correct.